# Error calling one Spring boot rest API from another rest API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote one spring boot api having method Post which i can able to call directly.

But when I try to call the same with another spring boot rest api I am getting the below error. [I know the error is all about the my URL is wrong] but as i mentioned I am able to call that same post method directly but not from the second api.

> Internal Server Error with message 404 and status 500

**Main Spring rest API**

```
@PostMapping("/callForSecondAPI")
public ResponseEntity<List<Attributes>> findByIdAndGroup(@RequestBody Attributes attribute) {

    String id = attribute.getId();
    String group = attribute.Group();

    List<Attributes> selectedRecords = attributesService.findByIdAndGroup(id, group);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(selectedRecords);

}
```

**Second Spring rest API which is coming the first API**

```
@PostMapping("/attributes")

public ResponseEntity<Attributes[]> findByIdAndGroup(@RequestBody Attributes attribute) {

    String id = attribute.getId();
    String group = attribute.Group();

    HashMap<String, String> attr = new HashMap<>();
    attr.put("id", id);
    attr.put("group", group);


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity<Attributes> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Attributes>(attribute, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Attributes[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:2342/api/v1/department/callForSecondAPI", requestEntity
            , Attributes[].class, attr);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseEntity.getBody());
}
```

I google a lot and followed a lot for tutorial, played with all the RestTemplate methods but nothing worked out.

When i debug the second API, I went into RestTemplate class and when it make the final call it failed and went into catch block of doInvoke method and throw InvocationTargetException it is on the HandlerMethod class of spring.

**Stack Trace from console:**

```
2019-08-11 14:26:49.576  INFO 17736 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms
2019-08-11 14:26:49.814 ERROR 17736 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 ] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.slb.dataplatform.dispatcherapi.controller.AttributesController.findBySsrIdAndScheduleGroup(AttributesController.java:103) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Can some one tell me what i am doing wrong or how to debug so that I can get to know the right place where i need to fix particular problem.

Comment: Could you please update the stack trace?

Comment: Either you're using the wrong host, or the wrong port, or the path to the first API is not /api/v1/department, or a combination of some of these.

Comment: Did you check to see if you're using the correct host name, port and URI?

Comment: Yes I checked thousand of times, also to verify that first api which i am call from second one, I called it separately from postman which is working fine. That is why it is blowing my mind since this morning.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake only, I copied the first api url into notepad and then compare with existing url i am using in the second, found out added small extra stuff into url which was the reason for that. thanks guys for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`404` Http errors are when the caller is unable to find the relevant resource at the server.

So your `B` server is unable to find the relevant URI in service `A`

I suggest to run in debug mode and check exactly where `B` is trying to call. Copy this URL to a `Postman` or other HTTP client program to re-check yourself.

Comment: yes, you are corrected myself I used wrong url which was the problem and that was very silly which from bare eyes was not able to see. thank you

Comment: @IndrajeetGour cool. I will appreciate if can also mark my answer as the selected one.